# Copy columns with varying row lengths to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy columns from A2 to unknown row length to a new workbook. 
The other workbook has other headers and I need to have Column A without header to Column C with another header and Column J needs to go column A and so on.

I tried this code

```
Sub SO()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Workbooks("Workbook1.xlsm").Worksheets("Orderheader")
Set ws2 = Workbooks("Workbook2.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")

lastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

ws1.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)).Copy

ws2.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _ :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

It worked fine once and now it doesn't work. It also doesn't seem to work for multiple columns, which I really need.

Now I get an error on "Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted you should qualify all cells with a sheet name in case it is not active when you run the macro. You will need to explain further the rest of your request as it is not clear ("Column J needs to go column A and so on").

```
Sub SO()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Workbooks("Workbook1.xlsm").Worksheets("Orderheader")
Set ws2 = Workbooks("Workbook2.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")

With ws1
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 1)).Copy
    ws2.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me. I wanted to copy multiple columns. So I copied the code between with and changed the cells and destination for ws2. This seems to work.